# Income tax calculator and global var problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

Complete beginner here. I've been trying to pick up programming in my spare time and don't really have any interactive resources to consult. I've tried my best to get a program working where I've tried to program an income tax calculator. I've pasted my program in its entirety.

What I'm hoping to understand from this is why the `tax_calc()` function is not saving variable `payable`. I've created a test line

```
print ('Test Tann:', tann,'Test Tmon', tmon,'Test tinc',tinc,'test payable',payable)
```

in order to check the var values and the only one that doesn't update is `payable`. Is it a global var problem?

I'd also really appreciate any other advice regarding my coding. It's my first program and I only really know how to use globals to change vars in this regard despite a lot of experienced users expressing that the global call is very unnecessary and messy or unpythonic. Also, whatever advice you have to shorten or make my code more efficient is really appreciated.

```
from decimal import *

#Hmm, looks like I have to define all vars and dicts before functions even if I only call functions after declaration? 
tinc = 0
tann = 0
tmon = 0
age = 0
payable = 0

#Define calculation for specific tax brackets
rates = {}
rates['T1'] = 0.18 * tinc
rates['T2'] = 29808 + (.25 * (tinc - 165600))
rates['T3'] = 53096 + (.30 * (tinc - 258750))
rates['T4'] = 82904 + (.35 * (tinc - 358110))
rates['T5'] = 132894 + (.38 * (tinc - 500940))
rates['T6'] = 185205 + (.40 * (tinc - 638600))

#Defines the actual range for deciding on tax brackets
tier = {}
tier['T1'] = range(0,165600)
tier['T2'] = range(165601,258750)
tier['T3'] = range(258751,358110)
tier['T4'] = range(358111,500940)
tier['T5'] = range(500941,638600)
tier['T6'] = range(638601, 5000000)

#Defines the brackets for age variable 
tierage = {}
tierage['T1'] = 12080
tierage['T2'] = 12080 + 6750
tierage['T3'] = 12080 + 6750 + 2250

#Asks for whether you want to enter monthly or annual salary
def ask_choice():
    print ('Would you like to input monthly or annual salary? Please select (m/a)')
    global choice
    choice = str(input('> '))

#Asks for age
def ask_age():
    global age
    age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))

#Asks for annual salary, all inputs done in floats to allow for cents
def ask_annual():
    global tann, tinc
    tann = 0
    tann = float(input("Please enter your annual taxable income: "))
    tinc = tann
    print ('Your annual taxable income is',tinc)

#Asks for monthly salary, all inputs done in floats to allow for cents
def ask_monthly():
    global tmon, tinc
    tmon = 0
    tmon = float(input("Please enter your monthly taxable income: "))
    tinc = tmon*12
    print ('Your annual taxable income is',tinc)

#Decides on and calls on which function to ask for for asking salary
def asking():
    global error
    error = True
#keeps looping until you enter Mm or Aa
    while error == True:
        if choice.lower() == "m":
            ask_monthly()
            error == False
            break
        elif choice.lower() == "a":
            ask_annual()
            error == False
            break
        else:
            print ("Input error, please input either 'a' to select annual or 'm' to select monthly")
            error == True
            ask_choice()


def tax_calc():
    global payable, decpayable, tinc
    if tinc in tier['T1']:
        payable = rates['T1']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 1')
    elif tinc in tier['T2']:
        payable = rates['T2']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 2')
    elif tinc in tier['T3']:
        payable = rates['T3']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 3')
    elif tinc in tier['T4']:
        payable = rates['T4']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 4')
    elif tinc in tier['T5']:
        payable = rates['T5']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 5')
    elif tinc in tier['T6']:
        payable = rates['T6']
        print ('You fall in tax bracket 6')

    decpayable = Decimal(payable).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
    #Decimal used specifically for money, defines two decimal places. 
    print ('Tax before rebates: R',decpayable)
    print ('Test Tann:', tann,'Test Tmon', tmon,'Test tinc',tinc,'test payable',payable)

def age_calc():
    global final
    if age < 65:
        final = payable - tierage['T1']
        print('You qualify for a primary rebate')
    elif 65 <= age < 75:
        final = payable - tierage['T2']
        print('You qualify for a primary and secondary rebate')
    elif age >= 75:
        final = payable - tierage['T3']
        print('You qualify for a primary, secondary and tertiary rebate')

    decfinal = Decimal(final).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
    print ('Annual tax after rebates is: R'+str(decfinal))
    print ('Monthly tax is: R', Decimal(final/12).quantize(Decimal('.01')))
    print ('You net salary per month is therefore: ', (tinc/12 - payable),
             'or',(tinc - payable*12),'per year')

def enter_another():
    print ("Would you like to calculate tax on another amount? (y/n) ")
    yesno = input('> ')
    if yesno.lower() == "y" or yesno.lower() == "yes":
        print ('Alright, let\'s start again\n')
        ask_choice()
        asking()
        ask_age()
        tax_calc()
        age_calc()
        enter_another()
    elif yesno.lower() == "n" or yesno.lower() == "no":
        print ('Thank you for trying out this calculator')


ask_choice()
asking()
ask_age()
tax_calc()
age_calc()
enter_another()

input()
```

Comment: Does it make any difference what inputs you use?

Comment: Add a final else clause to tax_calc and print an error.

Comment: I just used inputs which I could use the decimal module with, just to show cents. Will try adding an else clause to print error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the global variables are causing you trouble.
You have this near the top

```
tinc = 0
#...
rates = {}
rates['T1'] = 0.18 * tinc
rates['T2'] = 29808 + (.25 * (tinc - 165600))
rates['T3'] = 53096 + (.30 * (tinc - 258750))
rates['T4'] = 82904 + (.35 * (tinc - 358110))
rates['T5'] = 132894 + (.38 * (tinc - 500940))
rates['T6'] = 185205 + (.40 * (tinc - 638600))
```

This will use a value of 0 for `tinc` to set up the `rates`. However, you have a function later where the user inputs the taxable income (in `ask_monthly` or `ask_annual`). You will need to change the rates you use depending on the value tinc takes.

**EDIT**

If you change this into a function and return the dictionary, you can pass that to whichever functions use it

```
def setup_rates(tinc):
    rates = {}
    rates['T1'] = 0.18 * tinc
    rates['T2'] = 29808 + (.25 * (tinc - 165600))
    rates['T3'] = 53096 + (.30 * (tinc - 258750))
    rates['T4'] = 82904 + (.35 * (tinc - 358110))
    rates['T5'] = 132894 + (.38 * (tinc - 500940))
    rates['T6'] = 185205 + (.40 * (tinc - 638600))
    return rates
```

Change `tax_calc` to takes the rates:

```
def tax_calc(rates):
    #... as you were
```

and then changes your "main" function to find it out:

```
asking()
ask_age()
rates = setup_rates(tinc)
tax_calc(rates)
```

You can probably gradually refactor the functions to return the variables that are currently global and use that in the next functions, removing the globals slowly.

Comment: That does make sense...although is there a way I can avoid having the `rates` dictionary dig for tinc before it' specified? Should I possibly stick `rates` into the `tax_calc()` function itself?

Comment: @JerriZA I've edited to add more details. I bet you can find someone near you to sit down and pair program with or a mentor you can email code to for reviews. Try reading some books and get  a sense of goo style. Practise sending functions parameters and returning things. :-)

Comment: Thank you! This was pretty helpful and I'll try reading into it more.